Failed to find a valid digest in 'integrity' for the resource blazor.boot.json in .NET 8 hosted Blazor WebAssembly PWA
I'm working on a .NET 8 Blazor WASM PWA project. I've basically recreated the old template that used to be called "hosted" by following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Ur79_kHVpo. I followed this post https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/web-development/blazor-wasm-pwa-applications-updates-cache-busting-with/td-p/3920976 in order to set it up to notify the user when an updated version is available. But it seems to only work inconsistently. Sometimes when I make a change to my app and deploy it, the currently running apps almost instantly notify me that there's an update. Other times, it takes a few minutes to a few hours, or even not at all. And during the time when its not notifying me of the update, I'm getting this error in the console.
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://<my domain.com>/_framework/blazor.boot.json' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'i7j4OTqlUgpP/raiyVyl7zPhawvQWu4qtBIcCivBopA='. The resource has been blocked.

Now, I know there's a lot of threads about this already. But there's a couple of differences here. First, I haven't been able to find a thread where the file failing to load is blazor.boot.json itself. Generally that file is mentioned in the explanation as the file that contains the hashes of the other files, and the other files are being cached or something for some reason so they dont match the hash in blazor.boot.json. But I haven't seen anyone having blazor.boot.json be the file that fails itself.
Second, my understanding from reading a bunch of threads about this for several days now is that a lot of this problem was that the compiled files used to be .dll and got blocked, but in .NET 8 they changed them to .wasm to get around this. But I'm on .NET 8 and still having issues.
What's so strange is its not consistent. Sometimes it works immediately, sometimes it fails for minutes or hours and then suddenly works. It smells like a cache issue to me but looking in the console I see that the file is getting a header directing it to not be cached. And it doesn't appear to be loading from the browser cache.
I don't understand Blazor enough yet to know what the hash of blazor.boot.json is being compared against that it isn't matching.
If it helps any, my hosting set up is Caprover installed on a Hetzner VPS. The app is deployed using a dockerfile almost identical to that generated by Visual Studio. I am using Cloudflare for DNS and have caching set to "respect existing headers" and have even tried it in development mode to disable cache altogether. Also I'm not using the Cloudflare proxy on this domain, just using it for DNS only.
I can't figure out where the files might be getting cached at that would cause this. It doesn't have any issues running locally in debug mode. Only in production. What also points to a cache issue is if I wipe the cache and reload the page, it pulls all the latest files and works fine then. But I can't expect users to be clearing their cache manually and reloading all the time. That was the point of the auto-updater.
As mentioned, I set up the update notifier according to this article https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/web-development/blazor-wasm-pwa-applications-updates-cache-busting-with/td-p/3920976 and there are some comments there with similar issues. But they seem to be having issues on .NET 7 which resolved themselves on .NET 8.
I've disabled caching (as far as I know how) in Cloudflare and anywhere else I can think of. But it seems still like a cache issue. Except for the inconsistent amount of time it takes to detect the update, if it does at all.
I've also tried the solution many people suggested of deleting bin and obj folders before publishing, but it didn't help and I don't think it really applies here. I'm using Caprover hooked up to my repo to deploy. My bin and obj folders are not in the repo, so Caprover wouldn't be cloning them down when it goes to build and publish, it would be making them completely fresh from scratch.
I am not sure how to provide a minimal reproducible example since it would have to be hosted to show the problem, and I'd have to deploy an update to demonstrate it.

Did you ever figure this out? I'm having pretty much the same issue.
